Laravel sanctum SPA on logout not set user_id field null
I use Laravel sanctum SPA specifically through sessions and cookies when logging out the user_id field in Database is not set to null after the user logs out, but it remains until another request comes with the same session and same SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS in Origin Header and then it becomes null
I use sessions in the database
I use Laravel API Routes
logout :
    public function logout(Request $request)
    {
     
        Auth::guard('web')->logout();
        $request->session()->invalidate();
        $request->session()->regenerateToken();

        return ['msg' => "ok"];
    }

